# Is the goal of dependency injection frameworks to wire the entire program right at program initialization?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2

**DI frameworks** like **Dagger2**, Guice or Spring allow to wire entire object graphs. At some points though, these object graphs need to be instantiated (e.g. in Dagger2 this is through the use of components which are used in the code to initialize the object (sub)graphs).
**How should you use those frameworks?**

- Initialize the entire program (object graph) right in the program
  initialization phase? The clear advantage is that you can use
  something like dependency inheritance (e.g. subcomponents in
  Dagger2)
- Initialize different subgraphs at various places in the code and wire them together manually? May this be the only option if you are    dependent on dependencies that you only have at runtime and thus need    to add to the object graph initializer?

Comment: hk2 (https://javaee.github.io/hk2/) has been specifically designed for the second use case, as it allows for dynamic re-wiring at any time.  It's very useful for servers that may have plug-in architectures where the plug-ins can come and go at any time

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid approaches, but as [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) states:

> When it comes to request-based applications, such as websites and services, you configure the container only once, but resolve an object graph for each incoming request.

Comment: Well, but doesn't that mean that we still wire the entire app in the initialization phase, only just for every request? We still have only one dependency container with all the program's dependencies (excluding the ones only available at runtime)?

Comment: Correct. You configure/register everything once at startup (in case you use a container), but you resolve a complete object graph on each request.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what other options than containers exist? I don't see a use case where it would make sense to not collect all dependency at ONE central place. Isn't that exactly what DI frameworks are for. That and the ability to wire everything correctly together?

Comment: I agree, it wouldn't make sense to compose dependencies *outside* that one central place. This central place is often referred to as the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Within the Composition Root, however, you have two options. Either you use a DI Container, or you build object graphs by hand, a practice known as [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di//). It’s important to understand that DI is a *practice* (not a technology) and that tools are useful, but optional